# Can we limit the number of tweets streamed in tweepy.streaming

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I am trying to stop the streaming after 100 tweets. Any help will be appreciated. I just want 100 tweets

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = all_data["text"]
        username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
```